# Strings not being, correctly, written to JTextField/Area on selection of row in JList

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, jlist

I'm using a vector to store the information displayed in the JList and I want to use the index of the selected index to copy the data of that row into the JTextField and JTextArea. I am having some issues where the selected item isn't be shown in the JTextField/Area but instead showing the data of a previous selected index. Every second index has an issue of showing the wrong data, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 and then 11. Each of them will only show the right data if you select first when the program has just been executed. The print lines that I have added to the ListSelectionEvent listener shows the correct data of the selected index but it doesn't correctly copy it into the JTextArea/JTextField.

Selected right after the program was executed.
[image: Selected right after the program was executed.]

I selected a few other indices then tried to select it again
[image: I selected a few other indices then tried to select it again]

**code:**

```
public class EditFlashcardGui implements ListSelectionListener {

private JFrame frame;
private JPanel listPanel;
private Vector<Vector> flashcardMasterVector = new Vector<Vector>();
private JList list;
private JPanel tablePanel, dataPanel, textFieldPanel;
private JButton submitButton, cancelButton;
private JTextField frontTextField;
private JTextArea reverseTextArea;
private GridBagLayout gridBagLayout;
private GridBagConstraints constraints;
private JLabel frontTextLabel, reverseTextLabel;
Vector<Vector> masterVector = new Vector<Vector>();

public EditFlashcardGui() {

    frame = new JFrame("Edit / Delete Flashcards");
    frame.setSize(500, 200);

    Container con = frame.getContentPane();
    con.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    listPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

    columnNames.add("id");
    columnNames.add("front text");
    columnNames.add("reverse text");

    list = new JList(populateList());
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.addListSelectionListener(this);

    Font font1 = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20);
    list.setFont(font1);

    tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.add(list);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

    con.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    // south panel

    gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    textFieldPanel = new JPanel(gridBagLayout);

    // cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    // dataPanel.add(cancelButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frontTextLabel = new JLabel("Front Text");
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(frontTextLabel, constraints);
    textFieldPanel.add(frontTextLabel);

    frontTextField = new JTextField();
    frontTextField.setColumns(30);
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(frontTextField, constraints);
    textFieldPanel.add(frontTextField);

    reverseTextLabel = new JLabel("Reverse Text");
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 2;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(reverseTextLabel, constraints);
    textFieldPanel.add(reverseTextLabel);

    reverseTextArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 3;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(reverseTextArea, constraints);
    textFieldPanel.add(reverseTextArea);

    submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
    constraints.ipadx = 1;
    constraints.ipady = 1;
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 4;
    gridBagLayout.setConstraints(submitButton, constraints);
    textFieldPanel.add(submitButton);

    con.add(textFieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public Vector<Vector> populateList() {
    //flashcardMasterVector = flashcardDB.getList();
    //Vector<String> flashcardVector = new Vector<String>();

    Integer temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
        Vector<String> flashcardVector = new Vector<String>();
        flashcardVector.add(temp.toString());
        flashcardVector.add(temp.toString());
        flashcardVector.add(temp.toString());
        masterVector.add(i, flashcardVector);
        temp++;
    }



    return masterVector;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EditFlashcardGui gui = new EditFlashcardGui();
}

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if (! e.getValueIsAdjusting())
    {
        System.out.print("id : " );
        System.out.println(masterVector.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).get(0));
        System.out.print("front text : ");
        System.out.println(masterVector.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).get(1));
        frontTextField.setText(masterVector.get(e.getFirstIndex())
                .get(1).toString());
        System.out.print("reverse text : ");
        System.out.println(masterVector.get(list.getSelectedIndex()).get(2));
        reverseTextArea.setText(masterVector.get(e.getFirstIndex())
                .get(2).toString());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list.getSelectedIndex() instead of e.getFirstIndex() method.

Code :

```
        frontTextField.setText( masterVector.get(list.getSelectedIndex() ).get(1).toString() );
        reverseTextArea.setText(masterVector.get( list.getSelectedIndex()).get(2).toString() );
```

Clean Code:

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

    if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
        Vector masterVec = masterVector.get( list.getSelectedIndex() );

        System.out.print("id : ");
        System.out.println(masterVec.get(0));

        System.out.print("front text : ");
        System.out.println(masterVec.get(1));

        System.out.print("reverse text : ");
        System.out.println(masterVec.get(2));

        frontTextField.setText(masterVec.get(1).toString());
        reverseTextArea.setText(masterVec.get(2).toString());;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- have to read Oracles tutorial about [How to Use JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)
- you can't put `Vector<Vector>` to the `JList` directly,
- put value and to use `XxxListModel` only, but in this case have to create crazy workaround for `AbstractListModel`, use simple array instead
- `JList` is based on one dimensional array have to use `Vector<Object (or String or Double...)>`

---

- don't complicate simple things put this array to the `JTable` (to the `XxxTableMode`l), remove all synchronizations columns, remove `JTableHeader` if required, then output to the GUI looks like as `JList`
- `JTable.removeColumn` remove only column from view, all data are still presented and stored into `XxxTableModel` without any changes
- then selected (have to test for `-1 == none of row is selected`) row (have to `convertViewToModel` in the case that `JTable` is sorted or filtered) returns all required data from `XxxTableModel`

Comment: doesn't matter, you can use both, `Vector<Vector<Object>>` will be better for `XxxTableModel`